# Where is HttpContent.ReadAsAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpcontent

I see in tons of examples on the web using the new `HttpClient` object (as part of the new Web API) that there should be `HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<T>` method. However, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't mention this method, nor does IntelliSense find it.

Where did it go, and how do I work around it?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

It looks like it is an extension method (in System.Net.Http.Formatting):

[HttpContentExtensions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834253%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

**Update:**

> PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

According to the [System.Net.Http.Formatting](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting) NuGet package page,  the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` package is now legacy and can instead be found in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package available on [NuGet here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/).

Comment: Has this been deprecated in the latest client Nugets? Can't find it now (used to be able to).

Comment: It could well be.  .NET4.5 added a lot of new stuff as regards async/tasks (await, etc), so these extensions may no longer be necessary.  I'd maybe have a look here, for example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.aspx

Comment: I can get the same behavior with `ReadAsAsync` and specifying a JSON formatter but it was a handy shortcut.

Comment: @georgiosd I've just updated the answer. In the mean time `System.Net.Http.Formatting` looks like it's moved to http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/ package.

Comment: I tried for several hours and never got this to work.  Using `JavaScriptSerializer` instead.

Comment: I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application can I use that package?

Comment: @vcRobe Suggest you ask that as a new question.

Comment: So is it true that the method in the original question, `HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<T>`, is not in Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client?  What is the suggested replacement?

Comment: I see the suggested replacement in the other answer.

Comment: @JedatKinports Quite sure it doesn't.  The WebAPI.Client package require .NET 4.5.  I think the old HttpContentExtensions were for .NET 4.0

Answer (score 75):

I have the same problem, so I simply get JSON string and deserialize to my class:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Products");
//get data as Json string 
string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//use JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Script.Serialization
JavaScriptSerializer JSserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//deserialize to your class
products = JSserializer.Deserialize<List<Product>>(data);
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this does not answer the question, why did this get voted down?  Isn't it a reasonable alternative to `ReadAsAsync`?

Comment: probably because you didn't answer the question of where did the extension method go. Writing your own is a poor workaround

Comment: It is not necessarily a poor workaround, it is localised and hence not likely to get broken in future nuget updates etc. I'm all for it.

Comment: This assumes the reponse has a JSON content-type.

Comment: I think ReadAsStringAsync is a bad idea, using ReadAsStreamAsync it is a better choice in the solution that is not an answer to asked question at all :)

Comment: Folks -- This answers 1/2 the question pretty clearly -- "and how do I work around it". +1+1 (the other plus one represents the three plus ones I gave to people who found this answer useful!)

Comment: It's important to note this isn't feature par. You cause unnecessary allocations to read as a `string` just to turn into `T`, and you ignore the content type header. The source of `ReadAsAsync<T>` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs#L266) shows it toggles the formatter used and passes the formatter the `Stream` to deserialize, like the [JSON one](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs#L245).

Comment: That being said, `System.Text.Json` in .NET Core 3+ is the new kid in town and will probably underpin `ReadAsAsync<T>` in due course. In the meantime, you can just do `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());` if you don't care about the content type.

Answer (score 50):

If you are already using `Newtonsoft.Json` and don't want to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`:

```
 var myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(
   await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Trying to use the new `System.Text.Json` instead proved too much of a hassle due to "Allow non-string JSON values for string properties" not being supported.

Answer (score 33):

2021 Update: Looks like the method is removed in .NET5. Alternatively, you can use `ReadFromJsonAsync<>()` from `System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions`. It solves the purpose.

Answer (score 19):

You can write extention method:

```
public static async Task<Tout> ReadAsAsync<Tout>(this System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) {
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tout>(await content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Comment: It's what I ended up doing - I'm not going to drag an entire DLL for a 2-line method.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Thank you for sharing your code. Before your suggestion, I spent hours without any success. Your suggestion worked like a charm for my need. As `@Liz` mentioned no need to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` with unnecessary DLLS (at least in my scenario).

Comment: Nice to see the old questions, with newer answers still being relevant 10 years later!

Answer (score 7):

Just right click in your project go Manage NuGet Packages search for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client install it and you will have access to the extension method.

Comment: Who is complaining about what?

Answer (score 1):

Having hit this one a few times and followed a bunch of suggestions, if you don't find it available after installing the NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client manually add a reference from the packages folder in the solution to:

```
\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.6\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
```

And don't get into the trap of adding older references to the System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll NuGet

Answer (score 0):

Although I had the same problem, the answers in this thread didn't fully help me to fix the problem. For this reason, I decided to write the result of my research in this post. To fix this issue, follow the steps below:

1. Add the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) package to the project using NuGet. While inside the ASP.NET solution, open the Package Manager Console by going to `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console` in Visual Studio IDE and add the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package to the solution.

```sh
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 5.2.7
```

2. After its installation, check that the extensions DLL exists on your system. `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` file should be present in the directory shown below as a result of the first step.

```sh
{root-solution-directory}\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.{package-version}\lib\net45\
```

3. Manually add the reference to the relevant project. Right click on the **"References"** section in the ASP.NET project within the solution click on the **"Add Reference..."** section. Since the file `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` is an extension, it will not be listed when searched directly like other items in the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package. Therefore, to add the DLL file manually, click the **"Browse..."** button at the bottom of the **"Reference Manager"** window. Select the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` file in the directory shown in the second step and check the checkbox to include the DLL file in the project.
4. Include the `System.Net.Http` namespace in the project to use the features provided by this DLL in the project; `using System.Net.Http.Formatting;` declaration is available within the `HttpContentExtensions` static class.

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
```

**OPTIONAL:** You can achieve a similar solution by installing one of the [System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/) or [WebApiDoodle.Net.Http.Formatting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiDoodle.Net.Http.Formatting/) packages and following the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

In .net7.0 apps you can find it under `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget package.