# In MVC3 how do I get a DataContract-attributed object that was posted to my action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, datacontract

I have to implement a method that i declared like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"whatever")]
void MyMethod(InputContainer input);
```

where `InputContainer` is declared as a `DataContract`:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "whatever")]
public class InputContainer : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    //[DataMember]s inside
}
```

Now in my code I have an action to which the call will be mapped:

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult MyMethod()
{
    // How do I get the InputContainer object here?
}
```

I've only seen samples using [`ReadAsAsync()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10399324/57428) which is a dependency on one more assembly which I'd like t avoid. Anyway I suspect `ReadAsAsync()` is some helper method that I could replicate.

How do I get the `DataContract`-attributed object `POST`ed to my MVC3 action?

Comment: I don't get it, do you have some constraint which prevents you to accept this posted object as argument in 'MyMethod'?

Comment: @GoranObradovic: Not sure. What happens if a request comes without data posted?

Comment: Then if you add InputContainer as argument it will have null value, if it was an empty POST request.

Comment: @GoranObradovic: I've found the solution and added my answer. In short, no, it should not work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work out of the box. If I add a parameter of type `InputContainer` to my action - it will be default-initialized, the values in the POST body will be ignored.

Extra wiring [from here](http://gregbeech.com/blog/deserializing-the-request-body-into-a-parameter-with-asp-net-mvc) is needed. First an implementation of `IModelBinder` is needed that will access the HTTP request `InputStream` and deserialize the object with `DataContractSerializer`. Then a subclass of `CustomModelBinderAttribute` is needed that would return the abovementioned `IModelBinder` implementations form its `GetBinder()` implementation. Let's pretend it is called `MagicAttribute`. Once all this is done all is needed is adding the attribute to the parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult MyMethod([Magic] InputContainer input)
{
}
```

Comment: You were sending xml in request body?

Comment: @GoranObradovic: Yes, but I used a `[ServiceContract]`-attributed interface to compose and send the request.

Comment: Yes, but you forgot to mention that request body is composed from xml, that is why I suggested to use default binder :)
I think you should update question title to mention that, just to help others with same problem.

Comment: @GoranObradovic: What else could it be if not XML? Are there any other ways to get `[DataContract]`-attributed stuff serialized?

Comment: Yes, and well, this is the problem when assuming things :) As you post to the webapi controller, I assumed that you are getting that data for request from wcf service with `WebGet` attribute with `ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` which returns datacontract serialized to json. I did not know that you need and use xml.

Comment: @GoranObradovic: I don't get it. I just put a `DataContract` on a type - how would I get json?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26708/discussion-between-goran-obradovic-and-sharptooth)

Comment: My employers network does not allow chat :) I was not looking at your wcf method, but I saw it now. You can specify format for `WebInvoke` attribute. Default is XML, but you can override: `[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = @"whatever", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]`. Sorry for confusion, I was not looking if you did it, I just assumed you did and wondered why it does not work out of the box on the webapi controller.

Comment: @GoranObradovic: I see now. So will my question benefit from any clarifications?