# HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

When making a method call to a generic method within the same class, I am getting the following exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpContent)'

The method call is as follows:

```
CarMdRootMessage<List<v20.CarMdDiagnosticReport>> report = this.CarMdGet<List<v20.CarMdDiagnosticReport>>(string.Format("report/diagnostic?uploadID={0}", string.Join(",", uploadIds)));
```

It looked like an issue with the "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" NuGet package being out-of-sync between projects, but I have them all on 5.2.3 now and still have the issue.

I also thought this may be a .NET 4.5 issue so I've upgraded all projects to .NET 4.5.2, but I'm still getting the error.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I found this.  Didn't read it too closely, but might be your answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399324/where-is-httpcontent-readasasync

Comment: Thanks, but I have that NuGet package installed already but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to add a binding redirect in app.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and managed to resolve it by **removing System.Net.Http** NuGet package I had installed **and** **installing Microsoft.Net.Http** NuGet package instead (both provided by Microsoft).