# Is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client supported in .NET Core or not?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mediatypeformatter

I'm currently trying to do some JSON formatting using the HttpClient in .NET Core and MediaTypeFormatters. Especially the function "ReadAsAsync(..., MediaTypeFormatter, ...)" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync(v=vs.118).aspx) which was available in .NET Framework in the HttpContent-Class would be very helpful. As far as I understood, it can be found in the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client but I cannot download it because it is not supported in .NET Core.

Though I have read, that it should be:

- [Where is HttpContent.ReadAsAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399324/where-is-httpcontent-readasasync)
- https://www.techrepository.in/consuming-rest-api-methods-in-net-core-mvc-application

I know that it is possible to do the formatting using Newtonsoft and so on.

But does someone know, if that package will be available in .NET Core some day again? I could not find any information really...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTTP POST message in ASP.NET Core using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750451/send-http-post-message-in-asp-net-core-using-httpclient-postasjsonasync)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version 5.2.4 was released on 2018-02-12.

Thanks @whitney-kew @jaquez

---

The package is not fully compatible with dotnetcore now.
However there's workaround for this.
You have to edit project.csproj like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
   <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net451+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml" Version="4.3.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Xml.XmlSerializer" Version="4.3.0-*" />
  </ItemGroup> 
</Project>
```

Please refer to this github issue for details:

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1558

I think the new Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version (5.2.4) should fix this, but it's not released yet, maybe in late 2017.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version 5.2.4 final was released on 2018-02-12.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4-preview1 is available now at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.2.4-preview1, as of the first week of January 2018.  I was able to add it to my .NET Core library today, and it builds successfully.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, there's also the [System.Net.Http.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Json) package that uses the new Json serializer instead of Newtonsoft's.

The usage is slightly different than using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`.

```cs
httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Type>(uri);
```

There's a number of other overloads as well.