# Trying to deserialize JSON with surrounding [] characters usig JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using .NET 4.7, C#, JSON.NET, MVC 5

I have some input JSON:

```
[
  {
     "id" : 1
  },
  {
     "id" : 2
  },
  {
     "id" : 3
  }
]
```

This is provided by a 3rd party API

Normally I would use code such as, to deserialize:

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
orderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderList>(json.ToString());
```

However I am finding that:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
```

Crashes out with the JSON in question. I strongly suspect that the surrounding "[" and "]" is the cause.

I would normally add :

```
{
  items: [
```

to correct the input JSON.

Is there a better way, to deserialize it, as it seems this input JSON is incomplete although when I test it, it does seem to be valid JSON.

Possibly I should be using JArray instead of JObject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Normally I would use code such as, to deserialize:

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
orderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderList>(json.ToString());` hehe it is redundant ... why not `var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); orderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderList>(content);`

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @Mahdis I think missing commas are just typo in the question

Comment: @Selvin, yes probably, but he needs to fix it anyway.

Comment: Commas added, it was a typo. Thanks for the spot however.

Comment: Either deserialise to a list of a concrete class (the best way) or use `JArray.Parse` instead.

Comment: @Mahdi interesting that you think it is invalid. Was your concern about the missing commas or that you cannot have wrapping "[" and "]"?

Comment: @SamJolly just the commas. The outer brackets are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Instead of `JObject.Parse`, use `JArray.Parse` because the JSON is an *array*, not an *object*. This is not the best way to achieve what you want.
2. Deserialise to a `List<T>` where `T` is a concrete class that contains the matching properties of the object. for example:

   ```
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(json);
   ```

   This is better, but...
3. The best option is not to read the `HttpClient` response as a `string` in the first place and let the framework do the work for you. You should use the [`ReadAsAsync<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944541%28v%3dvs.108%29) extension method. Internally, this uses a stream and is more efficient than first going to string. So for example:

   ```
   List<Order> orders = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Order>>();
   ```

Comment: thank you for this, however I am not seeing ReadAsAsync as an available option. I can see ReadAsStreamAsync and ReadAsStringAsync. Also I have "using System.Net.Http;" Thoughts?

Comment: Used this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399324/where-is-httpcontent-readasasync

Comment: Sorry, I thought linking to the docs would be enough to figure it out. That question is also useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing commas "**,**" in the JSON. It should be like this:

```
[
  {
     "id" : 1
  },
  {
     "id" : 2
  },
  {
     "id" : 3
  }
]
```

And you can deserialize it like that:

```cs
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content);
```

Where `list` is a `List<MyClass>`

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```